# iTunesConnect does not show submitted binary

Tags: app-store-connect

It is quite often I am submitting binary, and it does not appear in iTunesConnect. Why? my strategy is that I resubmit it. But it is often that resending does not help. Do you know the reason why Apple does not let it appear?

Answer (score 1):

The binary will appear, but it just takes time. Sometimes it'll be visible within minutes, sometimes a few hours, depending on a range of factors (network bandwidth, server congestion, processing times, etc).

Also, some people don't realise that they need to click on the '+' sign under the Build section. That is, when it's ready, it'll appear and clicking on this reveals the binary.

My personal experience has been that it usually takes about a half hour to appear, but once it did take almost 18hrs. **I suspect at present there will be larger than usual demand on Apple's servers, reviewers, etc because many developers are updating apps, not just because of iOS 10 and macOS Sierra, but especially because of Xcode 8.1 and Swift 3.**

Also useful is [this site](http://appreviewtimes.com) for checking average App Store Review times (I know it's not what you're actually asking about, but it's a useful resource nonetheless).

Comment: But recently I am waiting for 2 days!

Comment: Is that just to see the binary? Or for the time it takes for them to review your app?

Comment: yes just to see binary

Comment: I just edited my answer - basically I strongly suspect that demand is very high at present, especially as developers update apps because of Xcode 8.1 and Swift 3. Plus iOS now displays that message to users which says: *"App name" may slow down your iPhone. The developer of this app needs to update it to improve compatibility.*, so that's creating a lot of activity from developers being shamed into updating! That said, two days is a long time to wait, but as I haven't submitted any binaries for about five weeks I can't give you a comparison. Hopefully someone else can.